# Merging two XML files using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have 2 xml files which I need to merge together using a style sheet

```
<AssessmentInput>
  <ApplicationData>...</AppicationData>
  <MetricList>...</MetricList>
</AssessmentInput>
```

One is ApplicationData and the other one is MetricList.
here is what I have done but it is nothing close to what it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ascii"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl exslt">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="ApplicationData" select="/"/>
    <xsl:param name="MetricList"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$ApplicationData/ApplicationData"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ApplicationData">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me. I don't have any experience with XSLT.

Comment: You have described the structure of your output, but what's the structure of your input XML files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given the following input files:

**ApplicationData.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ApplicationData>
    Whatever data you have in here.
</ApplicationData>
```

**MetricList.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MetricList>
    Whatever list you have in here.
</MetricList>
```

**AssessmentInput.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AssessmentInput />
```

the following transformation **merge.xsl** applied to **AssessmentInput.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/AssessmentInput">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('ApplicationData.xml')" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('MetricList.xml')" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

produces the correct output of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssessmentInput>
    <ApplicationData>
        Whatever data you have in here.
    </ApplicationData>
    <MetricList>
        Whatever list you have in here.
    </MetricList>
</AssessmentInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be replace your line as below:-

```
<xsl:param name="ApplicationData" select="/"/>
  <xsl:param name="MetricList"/>
```

with this below line one:

```
   <xsl:variable name="Application_Data" select="document('Application_Data.xml')/ApplicationData"/>
 <xsl:variable name="'Metric_List" select="document('Application_Data.xml')/MetricList"/>
```

i think this may help you..