# How to merge 2 XML files in to one with #Java Script or #XSL ?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jscript

I have 02 XML files, I need to generate a report with the data combination of both the files. either Out put as an HTML file or Single XML with using XSLT

**File1**

```
<FitnessCenter>
  <Member id="1" level="platinum">
       <Name>Kamal</Name>
       <Phone type="home">2921234</Phone>
       <Phone type="work">2581247-293</Phone>
       <FavoriteColor>brown</FavoriteColor>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
    <Member id="2" level="silver">
        <Name>Wasantha</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2934321</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581247-293</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>green</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
</FitnessCenter>
```

**File2**

```
<FitnessCenter>
<Member id="3" level="platinum">
        <Name>Aysha</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2926745</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581245-292</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>black</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
    <Member id="4" level="platinum">
        <Name>Nishani</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2925647</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581245-292</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>yellow</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
</FitnessCenter>
```

I tried to use below XSL method to combine these two files, but it didn't work,

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:copy-of select="*/FitnessCenter()"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2.xml')/*/FitnessCenter()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Please comment if anyone having a solution to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Look like your same questions is already answered on below post.

In your try , you have not used third file to do the required processing for final out put

[Merging two XML files using XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021205/merging-two-xml-files-using-xslt)

Comment: Im not using any application to produce files, Im using Notepad++ so i don't know how to link and see the output

Comment: You definitly need to have XSLT transformation engine to do required transformation ,you need to install plugin for Notpad++ for XSLT transformation. example in eclipse http://www.vogella.com/articles/XSLT/article.html

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/FitnessCenter">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Member" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="document('File2.xml')/FitnessCenter/Member" />
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming you want to merge all 4 members into a **single** FitnessCenter element, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FitnessCenter>
  <Member id="1" level="platinum">
       <Name>Kamal</Name>
       <Phone type="home">2921234</Phone>
       <Phone type="work">2581247-293</Phone>
       <FavoriteColor>brown</FavoriteColor>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
  <Member id="2" level="silver">
        <Name>Wasantha</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2934321</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581247-293</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>green</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
  <Member id="3" level="platinum">
        <Name>Aysha</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2926745</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581245-292</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>black</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
  <Member id="4" level="platinum">
        <Name>Nishani</Name>
        <Phone type="home">2925647</Phone>
        <Phone type="work">2581245-292</Phone>
        <FavoriteColor>yellow</FavoriteColor>
        <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
</FitnessCenter>
```

Comment: @ser3016153 Im trying a for loop to get all the output in to one file, So when using this "copy-of Select" should i use this before the for loop ?  or starting of the xsl file ?

Comment: @AnjalaFernando Why do you need to use a loop? I have edited my answer to show the result. If that's not what you want, please edit your question and show the result that you expect.

Comment: HI @ser3016153  How did you generate that single out put? Did you link the xsl file in to one of the xml file or is there any way to generate a new file combining both ? i'm bit confused.

Comment: @AnjalaFernando I have edited my answer again to show the entire stylesheet. When you perform the XSL transformation of the first XML file using the above stylesheet, the output will be as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

find it here...
i hope this will help you..
this is java solution.

[Merging different nodes of multiple XML files using JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316556/merging-different-nodes-of-multiple-xml-files-using-java)