# Merge two XML files into one in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm trying to merge two XML files using javascript into one whereby I'm copying over one node of one file into the other file. How do I go about doing this? I'm not sure how the solutions regarding XSLT work with javascript so are there any resources for xml manipulation using javascript?

**File 1**

```
<Salon>
  <Member level="platinum">
       <Name>Paul</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
</Salon>
```

**File 2**

```
<Salon>
  <Member level="platinum">
       <Name>James</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
  <Member level="silver">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
</Salon>
```

**Merged file**

```
<Salon>
  <Member level="platinum">
       <Name>Paul</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
  <Member level="silver">
        <Name>James</Name>
        <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
  <Member level="silver">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
</FitnessCenter>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge 2 XML files in to one with #Java Script or #XSL ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20739011/how-to-merge-2-xml-files-in-to-one-with-java-script-or-xsl)

Comment: @NicolaeMaties I'm not very sure how XSLT works inside the js code

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/hareko/js-merge-xml

Comment: There is always the quick and dirty way which consists in deleting last line of File 1 and first line of File 2 and merde files without further ado. But this can only be done in simple XML files like your example.

Answer (score 2):

DOM has the necessary methods. Create a target document for the result, then for each source XML, parse it and fetch the `Member` elements. Validate that here is something to copy and append the nodes.

```js
const mergedDocument = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "Salon");
for (const xmlString of getSources()) {
  const source = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
  const members = source.querySelectorAll('Salon > Member');
  if (members.length > 0) {
    mergedDocument.documentElement.append(...members);
  }
}  
console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(mergedDocument));

function getSources() {
  return [
  `<Salon>
     <Member level="platinum">
       <Name>Paul</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
     </Member>
   </Salon>`, 
  `<Salon>
    <Member level="platinum">
      <Name>James</Name>
      <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
    <Member level="silver">
      <Name>Peter</Name>
      <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
  </Salon>`
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following inserts file 1 into file 2, to create a merged file, but leaving file 1 intact:

```
const xmlDoc1 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(file1, 'text/xml');
const xmlDoc2 = new DOMParser().parseFromString(file2, 'text/xml');

let sources = xmlDoc1.evaluate("//Member", xmlDoc1, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);    
let destination = xmlDoc2.querySelector("Salon");
for(var i = 0; i < sources.snapshotLength; i++) {
  let node = sources.snapshotItem(i);
  let n_node = node.cloneNode(true)
  destination.append(n_node)    
}
alert(destination.outerHTML);
```

Output:

```
<Salon>
  <Member level="platinum">
       <Name>James</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
  <Member level="silver">
        <Name>Peter</Name>
        <MembershipFee>500</MembershipFee>
    </Member>
<Member level="platinum">
       <Name>Paul</Name>
       <MembershipFee>1000</MembershipFee>
  </Member>
</Salon>

alert(destination.outerHTML)
```