# How do I get a single Testcafe failure report from parallel runs on CircleCI?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, circleci, testcafe

What I am looking for is basically the test results that are displayed on the Tests tab in CircleCI but in an output file. Just like the test results on the Tests tab, the output file should include failures from each of my TestCafe test job's parallel runs. We are using artifacts but those are created separately for each parallel run.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an additional job, which will merge several report files into one. Use the [requires](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration-reference#requires) keyword to specify test jobs that should be finished before that.

```
workflows:
  several-tests-workflow:
    jobs:
      - test1
      - test2
      - merge_reports:
          requires:
            - test1
            - test2
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dmitry. Can you provide more detail on what the merge_report job would include?

Comment: I mean a task which merges several report files into one. For example, how to merge XML files: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354595/merge-two-xml-files-into-one-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65354595/merge-two-xml-files-into-one-in-javascript). Also, the following article describes a similar task for cypress tests: [https://medium.com/@gururajhm/parallel-tests-with-cypress-io-circle-ci-github-mochawesome-report-4fc29eb65da](https://medium.com/@gururajhm/parallel-tests-with-cypress-io-circle-ci-github-mochawesome-report-4fc29eb65da).