# Merging XML Files Using SAXON and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am new to `XSLT` and `SAXON` and I wish to accomplish the following:

I have a long list of `XML` files representing some benchmark, all of the following structure:

```
<benchmark>
    <xpath>
        <query>xxxxx</query>
        <ast depth="6" size="11">
            ...
        </ast>
        <schemas>
            <validation schema="xquery-3.0.xsd" valid="yes"/>
            ...
        </schemas>
    </xpath>
    <xpath>
        <query>yyyyy</query>
        <ast depth="6" size="11">
            ...
        </ast>
        <schemas>
            <validation schema="xquery-3.0.xsd" valid="yes"/>
            ...
        </schemas>
    </xpath>
</benchamark>
```

I just want to merge them all in one `XML` file containing all the content (all `<xpath>` elements and their childs) from all files under one root `benchmark` node.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seems like a basic problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am new to XSLT and SAXON and I was advised using them. I did not find a way to output a single file. In SAXON (command :SAXON -xsl:mergefiles.xsl -s:../../benchmark/ -o:./  ) when u provide a directory of files the output is still a directory and seperate files are generated

Comment: This should get you started : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021205/merging-two-xml-files-using-xslt/19023823

Comment: Which version and edition of Saxon is that exactly?

Comment: SaxonHe9-5-1-7J/saxon9he.jar

Comment: That is kind of an oddly old version but it should allow you to start with a named template and use the `collection` function to pull in all files from a directory e.g. `<xsl:template name="main"><benchmark><xsl:copy-of select="collection('../../benchmark/?select=*xml')/*/node()"/></benchmark></xsl:template>`. Run Saxon with `-xsl:mergefiles.xsl -it:main -o:merged-file.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to start the transformation with a named template and no input XML but to pull in all data from the directory with the `collection` function:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <benchmark>
    <xsl:copy-of select="collection('../../benchmark/?select=*xml')/*/node()"/>
  </benchmark>
</xsl:template>
```

and then call Saxon with the options `-xsl:mergefiles.xsl -it:main -o:merged-file.xml`.